# Git: Push project folders into their repositories

Tags: bash, git, unix, github

I'd like to write a script that, when run, pushes all the last updated files into the matching GitHub repositories.

Here's what I tried:

```
myPath=absolute_project_path
for i in $*
do
  if [[ -d $myPath/$i ]]
  then
    cd $myPath/$i
  
    git add ./*
    git commit -m "update"

    git remote set-url origin https://usr:pwd@github.com/username/$i.git
    git push -f -u origin main
  fi
done
```

But this is adding **all** the folders to **all** the directories: so myrepo1 in GitHub, gets myrepo1+myrepo2 files, and myrepo2 gets myrepo1+myrepo2.

Does anybody know the reason why?

*Notes on the workarounds tested, if needed: It seems that the staging needs to be emptied every time before changing file for another repository.*

*But i tried this also:*

*- Did a backup of my folders, then ran `git rm -f`, git add, git commit, git push (caused local folder to get deleted), re-copied from backup, and re-ran the script, but didn't help*

*- Also tried to manually remove all the folders on GitHub and re-push them, but caused Git to want me to do a Pull. But once the Pull has been done (which caused the deletion of my local files), a re-copy from backup and a new Push caused Git to ask to make a new Pull again... reason why of the `push -f`*

Comment: Git is not about folders *or* files. Git is about *commits*. Each commit contains a full snapshot of every file (but no folders: files just have names with embedded slashes in them). A repository is a collection of commits. Checking out a commit is a request to remove, from your working tree, all the files you had checked out before, and replace them with the files from the selected commit-archive-snapshot.

Comment: It seems as though you are trying to use one repository as if it were two separate repositories. Don't do that: just use two separate repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only a suggestion, but for this you can use already existing tools like [myrepo](https://myrepos.branchable.com/).

Simply register your repos:

```
mr register ~/gitHub/repo_1
mr register ~/gitHub/repo_2
...
```

then if you want to push all your repos, simply type:

```
mr push
```

if you wan to pull them all, type

```
mr update
```

an so on... read to doc.